# Use Stokes' Theorem to calculate surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Stokes' to calculate surface integral $$ \iint_{S}\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} \,,$$ where $ \mathbf{F} = \langle z,x,y\rangle $ and $\mathbf{S}$ is the surface pictured below. The boundary curve C, is oriented clockwise.

[image]

That's what the problem calls for. My questions are:
1) How do I parameterize the surface so as to know what numbers to take.
2) Why do we care about the orientation?

Comment: Do you think parametrizing the surface is a good idea? Is there even enough information provided in the problem to come up with a parameterization?

Comment: Why do you want the parametrise the surface ? Just apply Stokes theorem.

Comment: Well, how? I am under the impression that you need the parameterization to apply the theorem.

Comment: By Stokes's theorem the double integral is equal to a line integral along the boundary of the surface. In this case such boundary is the circle $C$ of radius 1 centered at the origin in the $yz$-plane.

Comment: How do I write this with integrals?

Comment: @IoannesMath01 $\oint_{C}\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$